# Count the number of <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible using jQuery to count the number of div elements?

I have this code:

```
<div id = "center">
  <div class ="name">text text</div>
  <div class ="name">text text text ... </div>
  <div class ="name">text ...</div>
</div>
```

And get number: 3

Comment: Can you post the code you use to count the divs?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$("#center div").length` will give you the count.

Comment: +1; You could also use `$("div.name").length` if you explicitly want to count all the `div` elements with the `class` attribute set to `name`

Answer (score 8):

`document.getElementsByTagName("div").length` will give you the desired answer

Comment: OP asks for "using jQuery" instead of plain old JS. Also, that yields 4, but I believe OP is looking to count `div.name` only.

Comment: Would also return 4 and not 3 as requested

Comment: OMG thank you for the only correct answer out of dozens of duds across many questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="center">
  <div class="name">text text</div>
  <div class="name">
       <div class="SomeOtherDiv">bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="name">text ...</div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```js
$('#center div').length  // Result: 4
$('#center > div').length // Result: 3
```