# How do I count the number of empty divs and ones in use using js?

Tags: javascript, html

Like the title says, I'm trying to count the number of empty divs and divs in use using js. For example,

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>123</div>
    <div>123</div>
</div>
```

There are 6 divs that are empty and 2 in use, how do I count that in javascript?

edit: Thanks so much guys, really appreciated the help :)

Comment: Refer to the answer to this question: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522002/count-the-number-of-div>

Comment: No, that doesn't answer what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using two selectors. You can get all and empty.

```js
const totalDivs = document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper div").length;
const emptyCount = document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper div:empty").length;
const filledCount = totalDivs - emptyCount;

console.log({ emptyCount, filledCount });
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>123</div>
    <div>123</div>
</div>
```

Or with a loop with reduce.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper div")
const result =  Array.from(divs).reduce( function (o, d) {
  const key = d.innerHTML.length ? 'filledCount' : 'emptyCount';
  o[key]++;
  return o;
}, { emptyCount: 0, filledCount: 0 })
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>123</div>
    <div>123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, love the simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the children of the wrapper element and use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get divs which are empty and then get of the length of the array returned by filter. To check if a div is empty, we can use the [Node.hasChildNodes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes) method. And for count of non empty divs, we can subtract number of empty divs from total count of divs inside wrapper.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

const numEmptyDivs = [...wrapper.children].filter(child => !child.hasChildNodes()).length;
const numNonEmptyDivs = wrapper.children.length - numEmptyDivs;
```

Comment: I like this answer, I personally try to make as much use of this "fluent" workflow as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll iterate through each div and look for divs with no text, if so total will increase.

```
let totalWithoutContent = 0;
let totalWithContent = 0;

document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper div').forEach(div => {
   if(div.innerText == "") totalWithContent++;
   else totalWithoutContent++;
})
```

Comment: I was going to add answer but a simple modification of yours would probably be better. You might want to add in else statement that increments another variable for the count of divs with content.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that an element is really empty (also checking other HTML elements inside it - not only text) you have to check the `innerHTML` attribute

```
const container = document.querySelector("#wrapper");
let emptyDivs = 0;
let notEmptyDivs = 0;
container.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(element=> 
   element.innerHTML ? notEmptyDivs++ : emptyDivs++
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const empty = Array.from(wrapper.children).filter(x => !x.innerHTML).length;
const inUse = Array.from(wrapper.children).filter(x => x.innerHTML).length;
console.log('empty:' + empty + ' inUse:' + inUse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the children of wrapper by using
`document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper>*')`

The above returns a node list. Now loop through that and check for `textContent` property of each node. If it is null, increment a counter by 1

At the end of the loop you'll have number of empty divs

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of empty (`innerHTML`, `textContent`, `childNodes`) and the logic of merely having two states, you can return both states by calling [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and passing an `object` as `accumulator` parameter by increasing its binary-state-key using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

```js
var tResult = [...document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper > div')].reduce((a, v) => Object.defineProperty(a, +!!v.innerHTML, {value: a[+!!v.innerHTML]+1}), {0:0, 1:0})

console.log(
  'Empty: ' + tResult[0] + '\n' +
  'Not empty: ' + tResult[1]
)
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>123</div>
    <div>123</div>
</div>
```